# How to populate without _id in mongoose with array of foreign key?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

I know I can use virtual in mongoose to populate without _id.
But My situation is something like this:

```
const storeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  store_id: Number,
  store_name: String,
  cart_tokens: [String],
})

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  cart_token: String,
  items: { type: Array },
})
```

My cart_tokens in the store schema is an array instead of one value.
I want the result of store be something like:

```
{
   store_id: xxx,
   store_name: xxx,
   carts:[
      {
          cart_token: xxx,
          items: [...],
      },
      {...},
      {...}
   ]
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**This will work:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
    let cartSchema = new Schema({
      cart_token: String,
      items: { type: Array },
    })
    
    
    let storeSchema = new Schema({
      store_id: Number,
      store_name: String,
      cart_tokens: [cartSchema]
    });
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema);
```